# How to prevent 'process stopped with signal 11' in TWRP?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, 7.0-nougat

I am trying to root my Cubot Rainbow (Android 7.0) following [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/root-twrp-cubot-rainbow-2-t3612133). Everything works fine, I am able to flash partitions with the SP Flash Tool and the recovery is working properly.

The recovery version is TWRP 3.1.0 by Jemmini. However, whenever I try to flash any SuperSU (whatever version from whatever website, including the ones from the tutorial) I always get the same message: status 11... which just means 'try again'.

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Formatted data and got left with only my SD content, which was expected. However, that didn't solve my problem. When starting TWRP, I always swipe to allow modifications to the `system` partition, and store my SuperSU zip in `/sdcard/`.

Comment: Tried [this website's files](https://www.supersuroot.com/download.html). Same error.

Comment: There's only one TWRP for Rainbow 2, and it's the third time I flash it. I have tried other recoveries for other Cubots, but they wouldn't work.

Comment: Seems to be a custom SU for your phone http://www.stupdroid.com/2017/01/root-twrp-cubot-max.html?m=1

Comment: Same error. I have no idea what's causing it, but it's pretty annoying.